# Removing quotes from keys of dicts when rendering to template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

is it possible to remove the quotes on keys during rendering a dict with `render_to_string` function so that I get `key:value` and not `'key':value` in template?

For example if this is my dict:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

and I render it like this,

```
return render_to_string('somefile.json', {'d':d})
```

Then in `somefile.json` I will get `{{d}}` as `{'a':1, 'b':2}`, but I want `{{d}}` to be `{a:1, b:2}`.  (without quotes on `a` and `b`)

How do I achieve this?

TIA

Comment: `{'d', d}`. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Why is the file called `somefile.json` when what you want isn't actually `json`?

Comment: @mgilson, it is a json file Im using, but it could be anything. This is just part of the code. The actual code does produce json. But don't consider the filetype for now.

Comment: import json
string_representation = str(json.dumps(d))

Comment: @simar That does not work. It gives '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' and I want {a:1, b:2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you could use is overriding the `__repr__` method of `dict` class or subclassing it and changing the method there. I have a the latter solution below.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        s = "{"
        for key in self:
            s += "{0}:{1}, ".format(key, self[key])
        if len(s) > 1:
            s = s[0: -2]
        s += "}"
        return s

MyDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
{a:1, b:2}
```

Comment: Why are you using  `if len(s) > 1:; s = s[0: -2]` ?

Comment: To take out the last extra ", ".

Answer (score 1):

I found Stepan's answer to be accurate and useful.  It was useful in my case to also apply the rendering recursively, and to keep quotes on string elements.  This extended version may also be useful to others:

```
class DictWithoutQuotedKeys(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        s = "{"
        for key in self:
            s += "{0}:".format(key)
            if isinstance(self[key], basestring):
                # String values still get quoted
                s += "\"{0}\", ".format(self[key])
            elif isinstance(self[key], dict):
                # Apply formatting recursively
                s += "{0}, ".format(DictWithoutQuotedKeys(self[key]))
            else:
                s += "{0}, ".format(self[key])
        if len(s) > 1:
            s = s[0: -2]
        s += "}"
        return s
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked the code to deal with nested list and dictinory.
Code :

```
class DictWithoutQuotedKeys(dict):
def __repr__(self):
   # print(self)
    s = "{"
    
    for key in self:
        s += "{0}:".format(key)
        if isinstance(self[key], dict):
            # Apply formatting recursively
            s += "{0}, ".format(DictWithoutQuotedKeys(self[key]))
        elif isinstance(self[key], list):
            s +="["
            for l in self[key]:
                if isinstance(l, dict):
                    s += "{0}, ".format(DictWithoutQuotedKeys(l))
                else:
                    #print(l)
                    if isinstance(l, int):
                        s += "{0}, ".format(l)
                    else:
                        s += "'{0}', ".format(l)
            if len(s) > 1:
                s = s[0: -2]
            s += "], "
        else:
            if isinstance(self[key], int):
                s += "{0}, ".format(self[key])
            else:
                s += "\'{0}\', ".format(self[key])
            # Quote all the values
            #s += "\'{0}\', ".format(self[key])
    
    if len(s) > 1:
        s = s[0: -2]
    s += "}"
    return s
```

Input :

```
data = {'a':["1", "3", 4], 'b':[{'check1':9, 'check2':"kkk"}], 'c': {'d':2 , 'e': 3}, 'f':'dd', 't':2}
```

Output :

```
{a:['1', '3', 4], b:[{check1:9, check2:'kkk'}], c:{d:2, e:3}, f:'dd', t:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found John's solution useful, Tweaked his code a bit to suit my case. To Quote all the Values in dict and keys without Quotes in Dict

```
{
  "variant": {
    "id": 808950810,
    "option1": "Not Pink",
    "price": "99.00"
  }
}
```

To

```
{variant:{id:'32036302848074', compare_at_price:'39.83'}}
```

```
class DictWithoutQuotedKeys(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        s = "{"
        for key in self:
            s += "{0}:".format(key)
            # if isinstance(self[key], str):
            #     # String values still get quoted
            #     s += "\"{0}\", ".format(self[key])
            # if isinstance(self[key], int):
            #     # String values still get quoted
            #     s += "\'{0}\', ".format(self[key])

            if isinstance(self[key], dict):
                # Apply formatting recursively
                s += "{0}, ".format(DictWithoutQuotedKeys(self[key]))
            else:
                # Quote all the values
                s += "\'{0}\', ".format(self[key])
        if len(s) > 1:
            s = s[0: -2]
        s += "}"
        return s
```